# WebSocketSharp returning "Input string was not in a correct format"

Tags: c#, websocket, websocket-sharp, websocket4net

I have a c# client that I am trying to connect to a websocket server. Using the Chrome extension "Simple Web Socket Client", I can connect, and send commands ok to the websocket server so I know the server is working ok and it is a commerical product.

I am trying to use the library WebSocketSharp and I get this error while trying to connect to the socket. Just so you know there are no proxy servers in play and the server is on the internal network.

```
2/03/2018 4:05:00 PM|Fatal|WebSocket.Connect|WebSocketSharp.WebSocketException: An exception has occurred while reading an HTTP request/response. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
                          at System.Version.VersionResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String argument)
                          at System.Version.TryParseComponent(String component, String componentName, VersionResult& result, Int32& parsedComponent)
                          at System.Version.TryParseVersion(String version, VersionResult& result)
                          at System.Version.Parse(String input)
                          at System.Version..ctor(String version)
                          at WebSocketSharp.HttpResponse.Parse(String[] headerParts)
                          at WebSocketSharp.HttpBase.Read[T](Stream stream, Func`2 parser, Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
                          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                          at WebSocketSharp.HttpBase.Read[T](Stream stream, Func`2 parser, Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
                          at WebSocketSharp.HttpRequest.GetResponse(Stream stream, Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
                          at WebSocketSharp.WebSocket.sendHttpRequest(HttpRequest request, Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
                          at WebSocketSharp.WebSocket.sendHandshakeRequest()
                          at WebSocketSharp.WebSocket.doHandshake()
                          at WebSocketSharp.WebSocket.connect()
```

Using wireshark I followed the stream and got this as part of the handshake

```
  GET / HTTP/1.1
  User-Agent: websocket-sharp/1.0
  Host: 192.168.0.29:55537
  Upgrade: websocket
  Connection: Upgrade
  Sec-WebSocket-Key: o0Smz22nOFWLW/3hvyvYQQ==
  Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; server_no_context_takeover; client_no_context_takeover
  Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13

  ....HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
  Connection: Upgrade
  Upgrade: websocket
  Sec-WebSocket-Accept: guJWynqtY1ZrPq+m6bfUGE2yJvA=
```

Any idea? I've even tried WebSocket4Net and that also had an issue connecting.

Comment: I guess there is something in the response the server returned as part of the handshake that the websocket libraries in C# doesn't like. What are my options?

Comment: Since WebSocketSharp ist quite small you could clone or download the [source code from github](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp) and add it as a project reference to your solution. Then set a breakpoint in e.g. `WebSocketSharp.HttpResponse.Parse` and investigate further.

Comment: I run a small test program, set a breakpoint in Visual Studio on the first line of `WebSocketSharp.HttpResponse.Parse` and pasted `....HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols` from the Wireshark log into `headerParts[0]`. It seems like the 4 dots (`....`) lead to the exception. If I reomve them then no exception is thrown.

Comment: Yes I noticed that too after I got into debugging the library. Is this an error onth server or library ? I’ve fixed the library now but I had to create a custom lib which I would have liked to avoid.

Comment: hoping someone is familiar with the rfc to save me having to figure out whether the server is non compliant